# Conditional expectation of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

how can I prove that for $X$ and $Y$ random variables we have that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \vert Y] = P(X = 1 \vert Y)
$$
if $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable?

Comment: Hint: use the general definition of the expectation of a discrete random variable. Suppose $X$ takes on values in the natural numbers. Then $E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xP(X=x)$.

Comment: Thank you. I see that it follows if I write $X= X \mathbb{1} \{X = 1 \} +  X \mathbb{1} \{X = 0 \}  =  \mathbb{1} \{X = 1 \}$.

Answer (score 2):

$E(X|Y)=(0)P(X=0|Y)+(1)P(X=1|Y)=P(X=1|Y)$